# Center Controls when form is Maximized

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I have a windows form that has a `Panel` that has about six `Label`s. Some of the labels are on the left on the `Panel` and some at the center. My question is that how do i make all the controls centered when the form is maximized.

For Example:

If the panel controls are like this

```
Label1                   Label2
           Label3
   Label4             Label5
```

This is what i want to achieve when the form is maximized

```
                          Label1                   Label2
                                      Label3
                             Label4             Label5
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At design time you need to center your controls and then go to the anchoring property of each control and **remove any anchoring(Left,Right,Top,Bottom)** they have. This will ensure that when form is resized they remain at their design time position.

Answer (score 1):

use Anchor property of each control

Comment: select control on the form, then open Properties window (F4), there is Anchor property