# How to keep win forms panels in same position when maximising

Tags: c#, winforms, formatting, sizing

I would like my win forms panels to stay at the top of the window when I maximise the form like it is when it's minimised.

This is the window when it's minimised (How I want it to be when I maximise) 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYrhS.jpg

I have tried the solution's provided on this thread [Center Controls when form is Maximized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908217/center-controls-when-form-is-maximized?rq=1)

The white panel is anchored to Top, Left and the Gray panel is Top, Right 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7M7r.jpg

The white panel is anchored to Top, Left, Right and the Gray panel is anchored to Top, Right, Left. The panels end up over lapping 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ncmk.jpg

The panels have no anchor and stay in the same place.
https://imgur.com/F37UDXy

How would I set the panels to be formatted the same maximised as they are when the window is minimised

Comment: Use a `TableLayoutPanel` having two columns and one row. Set the column size mode on percent and set them to occupy 50%. Set the `Dock` property of `TableLayoutPanel` to fill.

Comment: See a description of what Reza Aghaei suggested here: [How can I link a component's Size to the Window size?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55829513/7444103),